# Strtok() returning NULL randomly

Tags: c

I am trying to create a client that communicate with a server by sending 2 types of messages:

1. The word `QUIT` that communicate to the server to close the connection.
2. An operation with the following syntax: operator first_operand second_operand. For example: `+ 3 3`, `- 5 6` etc. (the operands must be positive integers, and there must be only 2 operands).

If the server receive an operation, it executes it and returns the result to the client. The problem is that the first operation I send returns the right result, while the following ones work randomly (sometimes they return the right result, other times the function `strtok()` doesn't get the second operand and returns `NULL`...).

This is code of the client that process the message written by the user in the prompt and that scan the message to check if the operation is written with the correct syntax (**WARNING:** the code is written in an extremely unprofessional and unclean way).

The code part that creates the problem is inside the `while(1)`.

```
#define MAXLENGTH 256

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int simpleSocket = 0;
    int simplePort = 0;
    int returnStatus = 0;
    char first[10], second[10]; 
    char* operator; 
    char buffer[MAXLENGTH] = ""; 
    char message[50]; 
    char terminationCommand[] = "QUIT\n"; 
    char space[2] = " "; 
    struct sockaddr_in simpleServer;

    if (3 != argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <server> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* create a streaming socket      */
    simpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (simpleSocket == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket created!\n");
    }

    /* retrieve the port number for connecting */
    simplePort = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* setup the address structure */
    /* use the IP address sent as an argument for the server address  */
    //bzero(&simpleServer, sizeof(simpleServer)); 
    memset(&simpleServer, '\0', sizeof(simpleServer));
    simpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //inet_addr(argv[2], &simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr);
    simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    simpleServer.sin_port = htons(simplePort);

    /*  connect to the address and port with our socket  */
    returnStatus = connect(simpleSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&simpleServer, sizeof(simpleServer));

    if (returnStatus == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connect successful!\n\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect to address!\n");
        close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* get the message from the server   */
    returnStatus = read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    if (returnStatus > 0) {
        printf("%s\n", &buffer[3]); 
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Return Status = %d \n", returnStatus);
    }

    memset(&buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));

    printf("You can execute 2 commands:\n");
    printf("1. Operations ( +, -, *, /, % ) with the following syntax: operator + first operand + second operand.\n");
    printf("Example: + 5 2 \n");
    printf("2. Termination of the connection with the following syntax: QUIT + press Enter.\n");

    while(1) {
        printf("\nEnter a command:\n");
        fgets(message, 1000, stdin);

        // the if with the termination command works fine
        if (strcmp(message, terminationCommand) == 0) {
            if (send(simpleSocket, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0) {
                printf("Send failed.");
                return 1;
            }

            returnStatus = read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

            if (returnStatus > 0) {
                printf("%s\n", &buffer[4]); 
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Return Status = %d \n", returnStatus);
            }

            close(simpleSocket); 
            exit(1); 
        }

        operator = strtok(message, space); 

        if (strcmp(operator, "+") == 0 || strcmp(operator, "-") == 0 || strcmp(operator, "/") == 0 || strcmp(operator, "%") == 0 || strcmp(operator, "*") == 0) {
            char *first_operand = strtok(NULL, space);

            if (first_operand != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(first_operand, "ANS") == 0)
                    strcpy(first, "ANS");
                else
                    strcpy(first, first_operand);

                printf("%s\n", operator);
                printf("%s\n", first);

                char *second_operand = strtok(NULL, space);

                printf("%s\n", second_operand);

                if (second_operand != NULL && strtok(NULL, space) == NULL && (atoi(first) > 0 || strcmp(first, "ANS") == 0)) {
                    if (strcmp(second_operand, "ANS\n") == 0)
                        strcpy(second, "ANS");
                    else {
                        strcpy(second, second_operand);
                    }

                    if (atoi(second) > 0 || strcmp(second, "ANS") == 0) {
                        printf("OK\n");

                        char operation[] = ""; 

                        strcat(operation, operator); 
                        strcat(operation, " ");
                        strcat(operation, first); 
                        strcat(operation, " ");
                        strcat(operation, second); 

                        if (send(simpleSocket, operation, strlen(operation), 0) < 0) {
                            printf("Send failed.");
                            return 1;
                        }

                        returnStatus = read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

                        if (returnStatus > 0) {
                            printf("%s\n", buffer); 
                        } else {
                            fprintf(stderr, "Return Status = %d \n", returnStatus);
                        }
                    }
                }         
            }
        }

        // after everything I reset the buffers I use to memorize the message and the elements of the message
        memset(&buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
        memset(&first, '\0', sizeof(first));
        memset(&second, '\0', sizeof(second));
        memset(&message, '\0', sizeof(message));
        memset(operator, '\0', sizeof(operator));
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why the second `strtok()` acts weird 90% of the times? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the problem is only about `strtok` please break it down to this, we do not need the full code with sockets then.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel the code is written in an unprofessional and unclean way, it would be best if you brought it up to good coding standards. For example, all those unbounded `strcpy` and `strcat`. And break things up into functions. I'll bet you'll find your problem.

Comment: `char operation[] = "";  strcat(operation, operator); ...` is for sure undefined behavior, if not all strings are empty.

Comment: After `char operation[] = ""; ` you cannot concatenate anything *at all*. Perhaps `char operation[1024] = "";`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17` )

Comment: the parameter to `htons()` needs to be an `unsigned short int`, not an `int`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  It is missing the include statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your 'real' code actually includes?

Comment: regarding: `printf("1. Operations ( +, -, *, /, % ) with the following syntax: operator + first operand + second operand.\n");`  This does not compile!  Please pay attention to the parameter types to (and returned from) the C library functions. Suggest: `printf("%s", "1. Operations ( +, -, *, /, % ) with the following syntax: operator + first operand + second operand.\n");`

Comment: regarding: `read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));` 1) the returned type is `ssize_t`, not `int`  2) when the value is 0 then the other end of the connection has closed.  The posted code is not properly handing that condition

Comment: regarding: `fgets(message, 1000, stdin);`  1) the buffer `message` is declared as 50 bytes, NOT 1000 bytes 2) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful,  Suggest: `if( !fgets(message, sizeof( message ), stdin) )  { perror( "fgets failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: regarding: ` memset(operator, '\0', sizeof(operator));`  the variable: `operator` is declared as: `char* operator; `.  So what this is doing is setting a pointer to NULL, probably not what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in you program:

You send newline terminated messages and you assume on the other end the `read` will return exactly the bytes sent by the other party, which is an incorrect assumption for the TCP/IP communications, only the order of bytes received is guaranteed, but the messages can be split on the way and received in chunks different from the sending sequence. You should instead read the socket into a buffer and only handle it once you receive a newline.

In your case, there is another problem which is more pressing: the buffer into which you `read` the data is not null terminated, so you should not pass it to standard C functions such as `strtok()`.